# Tex and pdf synchronization

Tags: vim, forward-inverse-search

I'm trying to make backward and forward search work between my `pdf` output in `skim` and my `tex` file in `macvim` with 'vim latex suite' using `PDFSync`. I think I did everything well, as when I `CMD-SHIFT-CLICK` my pdf file I get into the `tex` file. Two issues :

- if `autofold` is set in `macvim` it does not automatically defold my file when jumping the cursor. This would be useful especially when browsing my `pdf` file for errors and not have to defold every section in my `tex` file by hand.
- disregarding previous folding issue, the cursor appears on the correct line in my `tex` file. I'd like to have it on the right word. Especially when the sentence covers several lines.

Basically, I'd like to have the same behavior I had when using `texshop` with its internal editor and using `CMD-CLICK`.

Comment: Perhaps http://wolke23.at/2010/07/synchronization-between-latex-file-macvim-and-pdf-skim-with-synctex/ may help you.

Comment: @egreg. Thanks! The folding issue is resolved. But it still brings the cursor to the beginning of the line instead of on the right word... A behavior I'd like to reproduce from texshop.

Comment: Take Macro Lombardi's answer, in vim `set tw=80`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible.  PDFSync (but [SyncTeX](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html) too, which is better designed than PDFSync and should be used instead) maintains a file .pdfsync that basically saves positional information for each line of the input source.  That basically means that it is not possible to have finer data, for example at a word level.

A good practice, when using these packages, is to avoid particularly long lines and keeping them a length not exceeding, say, 70 characters: it is then almost immediate to find the correct word.

Comment: With texshop or texstudio the alignment is at the word level. With vimtex it seems random.